# How to set a variable in if-statement?

Tags: python, pandas, for-loop, variables

Ι have a problem with my code.  I run it and in command window shows me:

**NameError: name 'IA' is not defined (IA is the equation I show you in my code solution above)**

My code:

```
import math
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib as mpl
import numpy as np

dfArxika = pd.read_csv('AIALL.csv', usecols=[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10], header=None, index_col=False)
print(dfArxika.columns)

A=dfArxika[9]

for i in range(len(A)):
    if (A[i] >= 4.8 and A[i] < 66):
        IA[i]= (2.2*(math.log10(A[i]/66))+5.5)
    elif (A[i] >= 66):
        IA[i]= 3.66*(math.log10(A[i]/66)+5.5)
    else:
        IA[i]=(2.2*(math.log10(A[i]/66))+5.5)
```

How can I fix it?
I mean how can I find values of IA variable for each value of column?

To sum up, I would like to find a new variable (IA), which is based in A variable values

Answer (score 1):

I think you got a typo here:

```
A=dfArxika[9]
```

that should be

```
IA=dfArxika[9]
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo `A` should be `IA`, also for this the variable seems not to be declared:

```
import math
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib as mpl
import numpy as np

dfArxika = pd.read_csv('AIALL.csv', usecols=[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10], header=None, index_col=False)
print(dfArxika.columns)

IA=dfArxika[9]

for i in range(len(A)):
    if (A[i] >= 4.8 and A[i] < 66):
        IA[i]= (2.2*(math.log10(A[i]/66))+5.5)
    elif (A[i] >= 66):
        IA[i]= 3.66*(math.log10(A[i]/66)+5.5)
    else:
        IA[i]=(2.2*(math.log10(A[i]/66))+5.5)
```

Comment: look, A is in column 9 in .csv file. I want to find a NEW variable, which is based on A values in column 9 of my .csv file. Did you understand?

Answer (score 0):

might be a typo on your variable on the 10th   `A=dfArxika[9]` try changing it to  `IA=dfArxika[9]` or change your code to

````
for i in range(len(A)):
    if (A[i] >= 4.8 and A[i] < 66):
        A[i]= (2.2*(math.log10(A[i]/66))+5.5)
    elif (A[i] >= 66):
        A[i]= 3.66*(math.log10(A[i]/66)+5.5)
    else:
        A[i]=(2.2*(math.log10(A[i]/66))+5.5)
```.
````

Comment: look, A is in column 9 in .csv file. I want to find a NEW variable, which is based on A values in column 9 of my .csv file. Did you understand?

Comment: you of course wont get your IA from the csv file  value like that because you aren't defining the value  I will say you could store the column in a dic or a list then you could split values and so on if I understood you right which i hope so.

Answer (score 0):

You need to define IA before the loop.

Basically, you are trying to put numbers in a list that doesn't exist.

What you could do is make a copy of A and name it IA:

```
import math
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib as mpl
import numpy as np

dfArxika = pd.read_csv('AIALL.csv', usecols=[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10], header=None, index_col=False)
print(dfArxika.columns)

A=dfArxika[9]
IA=np.copy(A)

for i in range(len(A)):
    if (A[i] >= 4.8 and A[i] < 66):
        IA[i]= (2.2*(math.log10(A[i]/66))+5.5)
    elif (A[i] >= 66):
        IA[i]= 3.66*(math.log10(A[i]/66)+5.5)
    else:
        IA[i]=(2.2*(math.log10(A[i]/66))+5.5)
```

Comment: look, A is in column 9 in .csv file. I want to find a NEW variable, which is based on A values in column 9 of my .csv file. Did you understand?

Comment: If I understood correctly, then yes, in my code, IA is a new variable.